# Removing a picture that adds nothing to the question

Tags: discussion

I think this question is legitimate, but the OP has put a generic picture of a plane in the question.

[How do commercial airlines prepare for pilots falling sick during the flight?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12986/how-do-commercial-airlines-prepare-for-pilots-falling-sick-in-the-flight)

To me, this picture is gratuitous and, while adding a bit of colour, otherwise detracts from the site. I was going to edit it, but it would have been a fairly trivial edit and is also just reflecting my taste. It could plausibly improve readability and clarity. It's not worthy of either a downvote or a flag. What should be done?

"Nothing" would be acceptable.

Comment: [say again?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/12986/revisions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed it.

For future reference you can click the edit link and make the changes yourself. It will enter a queue for review by high rep users and if 2 people agree with the change it will become permanent and visible.

Once you reach 1000 rep (2k on a full site) the edit will become visible directly bypassing the queue.